[Flutter]Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '{FilePath}/Runner.app/Frameworks/libavcodec.framework'
Issue
I did Flutter run , then I get this error message.
I did a lot of research. But no one had the same symptoms as me.
I have rewritten the podfile, flutter clean, pod update, etc., but I still get the same error.
Error code
Failed to build iOS app

Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce
'{FilePath}/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/libavcodec.framework'


Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce
'{FilePath}build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/libswscale.framework'

Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|

        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      end
   end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

pubspec.yaml
name: x
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  jiffy: ^6.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  document_scanner_flutter: ^0.2.7
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  image_gallery_saver: ^2.0.3
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^6.0.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  media_scanner: ^2.1.0
  share_plus: ^9.0.0
  sqflite: ^2.2.6
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.0
  package_info_plus: ^8.0.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/


What I tried that (didn't work)
I have not tried many of the measures because I could not find any information on them in my research.
Sorry

flutter clean
cd ios && rm -rf podfile.lock , pod install
add Xcode Framework

